# Run Rails.application in a module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a simple ruby file that is in the root directory defined as:

```
module MyFile
  require 'rails'
  ...
end
```

This file needs to access certain credentials, but the following returns an error:

```
Rails.application.credentials.dig(:service, :password)
=> undefined method `credentials' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Why is this happening and how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to access `Rails.application.credentials`, you'll need to access the application. `require "rails"` only requires the bare Rails module, so that's why `Rails.application` returns `nil`. You'll need to access the module inside your Rails application instead of trying to access your Rails application inside the module.

What you could do instead is add the file in your `config.autoload_paths` so that it gets loaded when the application starts. More information about autoloading constants in the [Rails docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html). Then you can access the module inside your application and it will have access to the application data, such as the credentials.

```rb
# config/application.rb
module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.autoload_paths << "#{root}/lib" # or some other directory where you store the file
    ...
  end
end

# lib/my_module.rb
module MyModule
  def get_password
    Rails.application.credentials.dig(:service, :password)
  end
end
```

You can then use the module in the rails console (or in your models/controllers)

```bash
$ rails c
> include MyModule
> get_password
=> "mypassword123"
```

Or if you want to run the code straight from the command line (to access the password in a script for example), a Rake task would be a good option.

```rb
# lib/tasks/print_password.rake
desc "Print the password for service XYZ"
task :print_password do
  puts Rails.application.credentials.dig(:service, :password)
end

# Command line
$ rails print_password
=> mypassword123
```

Comment: Is there a way to just run a script inside the app folder, such as `ruby myfile.rb`, where that script can access the app's credentials?

Comment: I guess you could use [rails runner](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#bin-rails-runner) for that. Something like this: `bin/rails runner "include MyModule; get_password"` or `bin/rails runner lib/my_module.rb`

Comment: This sounds like it belongs in a Rake task.

Comment: Indeed it does, I'll update my answer to include that as an option!